# How to get multiple checked checkboxes values?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I fetched the checkboxes names from database, put them in array so they look like this:

```
pets = ['dog', 'hamster', 'cat', 'parrot']
```

Then I display them on my view in the following manner:

```
<div *ngFor='let pet of pets'>
  <input type='checkbox'
     name='pets'
     value='{{pet}}'
  />
  {{pet}}
</div>
```

So now the question is how can I collect only checked values so that I can send those to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an array of objects instead of array, because I think it will be barely impossible or very hard to achieve exactly what you want.

We can make a following variable:

```
pets = [{key: 'dog', isChecked: false}, {key: 'hamster', isChecked: false}, {key: 'cat', isChecked: false}];
```

And connect every object with `ngModel`, which will hold the value of each checkbox.

```
<div *ngFor='let pet of pets'>
    <input type='checkbox'
     name='pets'
     value='{{pet}}'
     [(ngModel)]='pet.isChecked'
     (change)='check()'
    />
    {{pet.key}} - {{pet.isChecked}}
</div>
```

When user checks any of the chechboxes, it's value will turn to `true`, and basing on this value, an array of checked elements will be shown.

```
check(){
   this.arr = [];
   this.pets.forEach(v => v.isChecked ? this.arr.push(v.key) : v);
}
```

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYRg1tK3wv6tMs7dPtAI?p=preview)**

Comment: @BillyLogan Cheers!